# Preventing shared library version incompatibilities on GNU/Linux

Tags: linux, shared-libraries, llvm, incompatibility

I've been tracking a bug triggered at the launch of my program. Here is the backtrace provided by gdb:

```
(gdb) bt
#0  0xb753f571 in llvm::cl::parser<llvm::FunctionPass* (*)()>::getOption(unsigned int) const () 
from ./libgdl.so
#1  0xb79aeab4 in llvm::cl::generic_parser_base::findOption(char const*) ()   
from ./libgdl.so
#2  0xb753f679 in llvm::RegisterPassParser<llvm::RegisterRegAlloc>::NotifyRemove(char const*) () 
from ./libgdl.so
#3  0xaf35f0b6 in llvm::MachinePassRegistry::Add(llvm::MachinePassRegistryNode*) () from /usr/lib
/i386-linux-gnu/libLLVM-3.1.so.1
#4  0xaef42b16 in ?? () from /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libLLVM-3.1.so.1
#5  0xb7fece9b in ?? () from /lib/ld-linux.so.2
```

In fact, the crash is due to the system using LLVM 3.1 ( for graphics related task ) while I'm using LLVM 3.0, which is embedded in my program ( libgdl.so ): 
When libLLVM-3.1.so.1 wants to call the NotifyRemove function, the call is forwarded to my version of LLVM in libgdl.so and it lead to the crash as the version are incompatible.

Is there any way to prevent such a mess?

Comment: why libLLVM-3.1 wants to call NotifyRemove? it should be LLVM 3.0 which is embedded in your program. Why is it entering into 3.1 in first place?

Comment: The system i'm using is Ubuntu 12.10, which is using llvmpipe for rendering OpenGL graphics, a software rasterizer that uses LLVM. ( My application is using OpenGL ( SFML library precisely ) ).

Comment: So during initialization, an OpenGL object must be created by SFML I guess, which lead the system to call a function of LLVM 3.1. And then LLVM 3.1 tries to call NotifyRemove which is wrongly redirected to the LLVM version embedded in my program. ( and then BOOM :( )
I tried to update the LLVM version I'm using so as to use LLVM 3.1, but in this case I have the same problem as described here :  http://lists.cs.uiuc.edu/pipermail/llvmdev/2009-March/021381.html